# How can I count a number of conditional rows within r dplyr mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I want to take a set of data, group it by one column, order it by another, and then count how many subsequent instances of a certain event happen. For example, in the data below... I want to add a column, call it nSubsqX, that tells me at each row, for that customer, how many **subsequent** orders have Product "X". Row 1 should result in 3 because rows 13:15 all are Customer C, Product X; Row 9 should result in 0 since there are no subsequent orders by Customer A.

```
         Date Customer Product
1  2020-01-31        C       X
2  2020-02-10        B       X
3  2020-02-12        B       Y
4  2020-03-04        B       Z
5  2020-03-29        B       X
6  2020-04-08        B       X
7  2020-04-30        B       X
8  2020-05-13        B       X
9  2020-05-18        A       X
10 2020-05-23        B       Y
11 2020-07-02        B       Y
12 2020-08-26        B       Y
13 2020-09-19        C       X
14 2020-10-13        C       X
15 2020-11-11        C       X
16 2020-12-06        B       X
17 2020-12-26        C       Y
```

For the purpose of providing a Reprex, below is the code to create the data frame.

```
df = data.frame("Date" = as.Date(c("2020-01-31", "2020-02-10", "2020-02-12", 
"2020-03-04", "2020-03-29", "2020-04-08", "2020-04-30", "2020-05-13", "2020-05-18", 
"2020-05-23", "2020-07-02", "2020-08-26", "2020-09-19", "2020-10-13", "2020-11-11", 
"2020-12-06", "2020-12-26")), "Customer" = c("C","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","A",
"B","B","B","C","C","C","B","C"), "Product" = c("X","X","Y","Z","X","X","X","X","X",
"Y","Y","Y","X","X","X","X","Y"))
```

I expect that I will need some sort of mutate function, but I can't quite get it right, I've tried:

```
df2 = df %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  arrange(Customer, Date) %>%
  mutate(
    nSubsqX = length(Customer[which(Product == "X")]))
```

Which gives the TOTAL of times "X" shows up, but what I want is the number **subsequently** to this one. I also tried:

```
df2 = df %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  arrange(Customer, Date) %>%
  mutate(
    nSubsqX = length(Customer[which(Product == "X" & Date > Date)]))
```

Which just returns 0 probably because Date > Date doesn't make any sense. I need a way to say Date > **THIS** Date. The solution I am trying to achieve is shown below:

```
   Date       Customer Product nSubsqX
 1 2020-05-18 A        X             0
 2 2020-02-10 B        X             5
 3 2020-02-12 B        Y             5
 4 2020-03-04 B        Z             5
 5 2020-03-29 B        X             4
 6 2020-04-08 B        X             3
 7 2020-04-30 B        X             2
 8 2020-05-13 B        X             1
 9 2020-05-23 B        Y             1
10 2020-07-02 B        Y             1
11 2020-08-26 B        Y             1
12 2020-12-06 B        X             0
13 2020-01-31 C        X             3
14 2020-09-19 C        X             2
15 2020-10-13 C        X             1
16 2020-11-11 C        X             0
17 2020-12-26 C        Y             0
```

I think this is just an issue of not even knowing what words to search, so I'm sure there's something out there that would tell me what to do if I could figure out the right search criteria. I appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: `Date > Date` or do you want `.$Date > Date`

Comment: I don't follow. 

Data > Date is what I have, which doesn't work. 

.$Date > Date gives an error saying

```Problem with `mutate()` column `nSubsqX`.
i `nSubsqX = length(Customer[which(Product == "X" & Date > .$Date)])`.
i longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length```

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: @akrun I edited the question to show the expected output. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` only solution:

The trick is to substract the grouping number of X (e.g. `cumsum(Product=="X")`  from the sum of X (e.g. `sum(Product=="X")`  in each `Customer` group:

```
library(dplyr)

  df %>%
    arrange(Customer, Date) %>%
    group_by(Customer) %>%
    mutate(nSubsqX1 = sum(Product=="X") - cumsum(Product=="X"))
```

```
   Date       Customer Product nSubsqX1
   <date>     <chr>    <chr>      <int>
 1 2020-05-18 A        X              0
 2 2020-02-10 B        X              5
 3 2020-02-12 B        Y              5
 4 2020-03-04 B        Z              5
 5 2020-03-29 B        X              4
 6 2020-04-08 B        X              3
 7 2020-04-30 B        X              2
 8 2020-05-13 B        X              1
 9 2020-05-23 B        Y              1
10 2020-07-02 B        Y              1
11 2020-08-26 B        Y              1
12 2020-12-06 B        X              0
13 2020-01-31 C        X              3
14 2020-09-19 C        X              2
15 2020-10-13 C        X              1
16 2020-11-11 C        X              0
17 2020-12-26 C        Y              0
```

Comment: Duh! So simple! I should have thought of that! Thanks TarJae!!

Comment: I have a follow up question on this, if you have time to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130245/in-r-how-can-i-group-by-one-column-and-conditionally-sum-another

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `tidyverse` - `arrange` by 'Customer', 'Date', then grouped by 'Customer', `replace` the vector of `NA` elements, where the 'Product' is 'X' with `rev`erse sequence of the count of 'X' values, then we either use `tidyr::fill` or can use `zoo::na.locf0` to fill the NA elements with previous non-NA values

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(Customer, Date) %>% 
  group_by(Customer) %>% 
  mutate(new = zoo::na.locf0(replace(rep(NA_real_, n()), 
      Product == "X", rev(seq_len(sum(Product == "X")))-1))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 17 × 4
   Date       Customer Product   new
   <date>     <chr>    <chr>   <dbl>
 1 2020-05-18 A        X           0
 2 2020-02-10 B        X           5
 3 2020-02-12 B        Y           5
 4 2020-03-04 B        Z           5
 5 2020-03-29 B        X           4
 6 2020-04-08 B        X           3
 7 2020-04-30 B        X           2
 8 2020-05-13 B        X           1
 9 2020-05-23 B        Y           1
10 2020-07-02 B        Y           1
11 2020-08-26 B        Y           1
12 2020-12-06 B        X           0
13 2020-01-31 C        X           3
14 2020-09-19 C        X           2
15 2020-10-13 C        X           1
16 2020-11-11 C        X           0
17 2020-12-26 C        Y           0
```

---

Similar option can be done with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(Customer, Date)][Product == "X", 
   nSubsqx := rev(seq_len(.N)) - 1, Customer][, 
      nSubsqx := nafill(nSubsqx, "locf"), Customer][]
```

-output

```
ndex: <Product>
          Date Customer Product nSubsqx
        <Date>   <char>  <char>   <num>
 1: 2020-05-18        A       X       0
 2: 2020-02-10        B       X       5
 3: 2020-02-12        B       Y       5
 4: 2020-03-04        B       Z       5
 5: 2020-03-29        B       X       4
 6: 2020-04-08        B       X       3
 7: 2020-04-30        B       X       2
 8: 2020-05-13        B       X       1
 9: 2020-05-23        B       Y       1
10: 2020-07-02        B       Y       1
11: 2020-08-26        B       Y       1
12: 2020-12-06        B       X       0
13: 2020-01-31        C       X       3
14: 2020-09-19        C       X       2
15: 2020-10-13        C       X       1
16: 2020-11-11        C       X       0
17: 2020-12-26        C       Y       0
```

Comment: I have a follow up question on this, if you have some time to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130245/in-r-how-can-i-group-by-one-column-and-conditionally-sum-another

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(Customer,Date)] %>% 
  .[Product=="X", nSubsqX:=.N-1:.N, by=.(Customer)] %>% 
  .[order(Customer,Date),nSubsqX:=zoo::na.locf(nSubsqX)] %>% 
  .[]
```

Output:

```
          Date Customer Product    nSubsqX
        <Date>   <char>  <char> <int>
 1: 2020-05-18        A       X     0
 2: 2020-02-10        B       X     5
 3: 2020-02-12        B       Y     5
 4: 2020-03-04        B       Z     5
 5: 2020-03-29        B       X     4
 6: 2020-04-08        B       X     3
 7: 2020-04-30        B       X     2
 8: 2020-05-13        B       X     1
 9: 2020-05-23        B       Y     1
10: 2020-07-02        B       Y     1
11: 2020-08-26        B       Y     1
12: 2020-12-06        B       X     0
13: 2020-01-31        C       X     3
14: 2020-09-19        C       X     2
15: 2020-10-13        C       X     1
16: 2020-11-11        C       X     0
17: 2020-12-26        C       Y     0
```

`data.table` explanation:

1. use `setDT()` to set df to data.table
2. We order by Customer and then date
3. in `i`, we limit to Product = "X"
4. in `j`, we create (by group) the `nSubsqX`, by assigning the value as the number of rows in the group (which is `.N`) minus the row number of the group (which can be generated on the fly as a sequence, like `1:.N`)
5. in `by`, we set the group columns; in this case we want to group by `Customer`
6. use zoo::na.locf to fill

Comment: Woah! That math checks out on the first one, definitely. But could you help me understand what it's doing? I know I can look at ?setDT, but I don't understand a lot of the structure here like := and .N (which isn't discussed in the ?setDT help file). Thanks for the help! The second solution isn't correct though.

Comment: hmm, I think the second one is also correct (i did have an extra `id` column in there, which I have removed, but the values appear to be the same).

Comment: Re data.table explanation, I'll add to the solution for you

Comment: Oh, ok looking at it a little deeper... they're both not quite correct. They're counting the number of subsequent times Product and Customer equal the current line. But I specifically want to know how many time X is the product for that customer moving forward. See my edit to my question where I show the expected outcome.

Comment: Isn't this wrong? `data.table`: See row 3, `nSubsqX == 3` but there are 5 subsequent products `"X"`. `dplyr`: `n()-row_number()` gives the number of subsequent rows, not the ones with product `"X"`.

Comment: thanks all for catching my errors. see update

Comment: This answer fives me an error: ```In is.na(object) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'```

Comment: Sorry. Fixed now.  My original name for the variable id, had not been completely replaced with nSubsqX

Comment: Also, TarJae's answer is clearly the better choice, especially if it is converted to data.table approach, which will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks langtang. I have a follow up question, if you want to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130245/in-r-how-can-i-group-by-one-column-and-conditionally-sum-another