# In R, how can I group by one column and conditionally sum another?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, cumsum

This is an add on to my previous question:
[How can I count a number of conditional rows within r dplyr mutate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72119437/how-can-i-count-a-number-of-conditional-rows-within-r-dplyr-mutate)

Let's say I have the data frame below. In my previous question I asked how I could calculate at each row how many subsequent times that row's customer ordered Product X (literally X, not the Product associated with the row), which is now given in nSubsqX. Now, I want to know the sum of the cost associated with those subsequent orders of X. I have manually entered the answer into nCostSubsqX below, but I don't understand how to do it programmatically.

```
   Date       Customer Product  cost nSubsqX nCostSubsqX
 1 2020-05-18 A        X           9       0           0
 2 2020-02-10 B        X           2       5          42
 3 2020-02-12 B        Y           3       5          42
 4 2020-03-04 B        Z           4       5          42
 5 2020-03-29 B        X           5       4          37
 6 2020-04-08 B        X           6       3          31
 7 2020-04-30 B        X           7       2          24
 8 2020-05-13 B        X           8       1           5
 9 2020-05-23 B        Y          10       1           5
10 2020-07-02 B        Y          11       1           5
11 2020-08-26 B        Y          12       1           5
12 2020-12-06 B        X          16       0           0
13 2020-01-31 C        X           1       3          42
14 2020-09-19 C        X          13       2          60
15 2020-10-13 C        X          14       1          15
16 2020-11-11 C        X          15       0           0
17 2020-12-26 C        Y          17       0           0
```

For the purpose of providing a Reprex, below is the code to create the data frame.

```
df = data.frame("Date" = as.Date(c("2020-01-31", "2020-02-10", "2020-02-12", 
"2020-03-04", "2020-03-29", "2020-04-08", "2020-04-30", "2020-05-13", "2020-05-18", 
"2020-05-23", "2020-07-02", "2020-08-26", "2020-09-19", "2020-10-13", "2020-11-11", 
"2020-12-06", "2020-12-26")), "Customer" = c("C","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","A",
"B","B","B","C","C","C","B","C"), "Product" = c("X","X","Y","Z","X","X","X","X","X",
"Y","Y","Y","X","X","X","X","Y"))

df$cost = seq(nrow(df))
```

Below is the code that gets me nSubsqX:

```
df %>%
  arrange(Customer, Date) %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  mutate(
    nSubsqX = sum(Product=="X") - cumsum(Product=="X"))
```

Now I need to understand how to make the array the rows where Product is X, but from the cost column rather than from the Product column itself. **Any thoughts?**

Attempt 1, gives an error.

```
df %>%
  arrange(Customer, Date) %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  mutate(
    nSubsqX = sum(Product=="X") - cumsum(Product=="X"),
    nCostSubsqX = sum(cost[which(Product == "X")]) - cumsum(cost[which(Product == "X")]))
...
Error in `mutate_cols()`:
  Problem with `mutate()` column `nCostSubsqX`.
  `nCostSubsqX = sum(cost[which(Product == "X")]) - ...`.
  `nCostSubsqX` must be size 11 or 1, not 6.
  The error occurred in group 2: Customer = "B".
```

Attempt 2, where the math isn't right. The nCostSubsqX column needs to have the cum cost to this point removed.

```
df %>%
  arrange(Customer, Date) %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  mutate(
    nSubsqX = sum(Product=="X") - cumsum(Product=="X"),
    nCostSubsqX = zoo::na.locf0(replace(rep(NA_real_, n()), 
                                        Product == "X", rev(seq_len(sum(cost[which(Product == "X")]))))))
...
   Date       Customer Product  cost nSubsqX nCostSubsqX
 1 2020-05-18 A        X           9       0           9
 2 2020-02-10 B        X           2       5          44
 3 2020-02-12 B        Y           3       5          44
 4 2020-03-04 B        Z           4       5          44
 5 2020-03-29 B        X           5       4          43
 6 2020-04-08 B        X           6       3          42
 7 2020-04-30 B        X           7       2          41
 8 2020-05-13 B        X           8       1          40
 9 2020-05-23 B        Y          10       1          40
10 2020-07-02 B        Y          11       1          40
11 2020-08-26 B        Y          12       1          40
12 2020-12-06 B        X          16       0          39
13 2020-01-31 C        X           1       3          43
14 2020-09-19 C        X          13       2          42
15 2020-10-13 C        X          14       1          41
16 2020-11-11 C        X          15       0          40
17 2020-12-26 C        Y          17       0          40
```

Attempt 3, I don't know what the math here is doing, but it ain't right!

```
df %>%
  arrange(Customer, Date) %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  mutate(
    nSubsqX = sum(Product=="X") - cumsum(Product=="X"),
    nCostSubsqX = zoo::na.locf0(replace(rep(NA_real_, n()), 
                       Product == "X", rev(seq_len(sum(cost[which(Product == "X")])))))-
                  zoo::na.locf0(ifelse(Product == "X",cumsum(cost[which(Product == "X")]),NA)))
```

Comment: Where is your `cost` column in your dataframe?

Comment: It's getting difficult to follow. But I think the issue with attempt 1 is  that `cost[which(Product == "X")]` is too short.  Try using `cost * (Product == "X")` that has the correct length.

Comment: @Quinten - sorry about that.... updated the reprex code!

Comment: @bdecaf omg! that worked! thank you! Do you want to put it as an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt 1 was almost there. It's important that the number of rows is maintained. Replace `cost[which(Product == "X")]` with `cost*(Product=="X")` (a dirty trick).
Btw. the `which` is unnecessary.

The snippet would be:

```
df %>%
  arrange(Customer, Date) %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  mutate(
    nSubsqX = sum(Product=="X") - cumsum(Product=="X"),
    nCostSubsqX = sum(cost[Product == "X"]) - cumsum(cost*(Product == "X")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach, if you are interested.

```
library(data.table)

f <- function(p,co=rep(1,length(p))) {
  sapply(seq_along(p), \(i) sum(co[-i:0][p[-i:0]=="X"]))
}

setDT(df)[
  order(Date,Customer),
  `:=`(nSubsqX = f(Product),nCostSubsqx=f(Product, cost)),
  by=Customer
]
```

In this approach, I actually use the same function `f()` for both `nSubsqX`, and for `nCostSubsqx`; the only difference is whether `cost` is additionally passed to `f()` as the `co` parameter, or the default `co` parameter is used.

Output:

```
          Date Customer Product  cost nSubsqX nCostSubsqx
        <Date>   <char>  <char> <int>   <num>       <int>
 1: 2020-01-31        C       X     1       3          42
 2: 2020-02-10        B       X     2       5          42
 3: 2020-02-12        B       Y     3       5          42
 4: 2020-03-04        B       Z     4       5          42
 5: 2020-03-29        B       X     5       4          37
 6: 2020-04-08        B       X     6       3          31
 7: 2020-04-30        B       X     7       2          24
 8: 2020-05-13        B       X     8       1          16
 9: 2020-05-18        A       X     9       0           0
10: 2020-05-23        B       Y    10       1          16
11: 2020-07-02        B       Y    11       1          16
12: 2020-08-26        B       Y    12       1          16
13: 2020-09-19        C       X    13       2          29
14: 2020-10-13        C       X    14       1          15
15: 2020-11-11        C       X    15       0           0
16: 2020-12-06        B       X    16       0           0
17: 2020-12-26        C       Y    17       0           0
```